# Generating titles in Vue with entity names

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, frontend

Here's one of my routing components:

```
const ExpoHardware = () => import('../components/mainviews/ExpoHardware'/* webpackChunkName: "ExpoHardware" */);
const ExpoDevice = () => import('../components/mainviews/ExpoDevice'/* webpackChunkName: "ExpoDevice" */);

export default [
    {
        path: '/hardware',
        name: 'hardware.index',
        component: ExpoHardware,
        meta: { requiresAuth: true, permission: 'devicesTab', title: 'Devices' }
    },
    {
        path: '/device/:id',
        name: 'hardware.device',
        component: ExpoDevice,
        meta: { requiresAuth: true, permission: 'devicesTab', title: "?????"}
    }
]
```

I have no problem with fixed titles, like the whole devices tab, but I would  like to name every page with device name e.g. "Player XCF-190-22" and all of it is stored in database. I think it's quite common case, but I don't know how to approach it. I was thinking about loading every device to vuex store and then assigning it or maybe at least Redis. I don't want to touch database before every route hit. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to touch database before every route hit. Ideas?

If you are uncompromising on this point, you must "touch databse" after the route has been hit.

You can listen this redirection with one of the [Vue router hook](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) in order to update the meta as desired.

Comment: I was thinking about hitting database once after loading the app and then caching all titles in store, I just don't want to do it every time I move to another subpage.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to modify your template slightly to handle title being a function. So instead of:

```
<title>{{ $route.meta.title }}</title>
```

Do

```
<title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
...
computed: {
  pageTitle () {
    const title = this.$route.meta.title
    if (typeof(title) === 'function') {
      return title.(this.$route)
    } else {
      return title
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can define dynamic route:

```
{
    path: '/device/:id',
    name: 'hardware.device',
    component: ExpoDevice,
    meta: { 
      requiresAuth: true,
      permission: 'devicesTab',
      title (route) { return `Device ${route.params.id}` }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the good old

```
document.title="Device ABC"
```

after loading the data in your view component? I know that's not vue like but the simplest approach...